# Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments

Tags: ios, xcode

An alert shows up when I run my project in Xcode.

```
Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments
```

I checked in the build settings but can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see some code to be able to help better but right of the bat you can try resetting the simulator. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Choose correct Scheme which you want to run, you can find them in menu `Product/Scheme`

Answer (score 0):

One of these worked for me:

- cleaning project (Product/Clean)
- cleaning derived data (Window/Projects)
- reopening XCode and the project
- removing the scheme and re-creating it (Product/Scheme/Manage Schemes)
- changing location of Derived Data (XCode/Preferences/Locations, changing Derived Data to: Relative)